# C# setup doesn't t start in Windows Xp

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje

i've created a Visual Studio Installer in .NET 4.0 for my Windows Service.
The installer works on my computer (Windows 10 64 bit), on Windows 7(32 bit) but it doesn't work on Windows Xp 32 bit, the installer doesn't start and appears a window with this message:

> "Installation doesn't complete. Installation program interrupted
>   before the installation of " ". Start the installation program again before
>   trying again. Choose Close to exit".

.NET 4.0 is installed.
There is no other details, what can i do for debugging the problem?
Thank you very much for your attention

Some chunk of LogFile.txt:

> Start operation 13:19:48: INSTALL. 13:19:48 Operation: DIRCA_CheckFX.
>   Start operation 13:19:48: DIRCA_CheckFX.
>  Action ended 13:19:48:
>   DIRCA_CheckFX. Return value 3. 
> 13:19:48 Operation: FatalErrorForm.
>   Start operation 13:19:48: FatalErrorForm.
>   2898. Information VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0, MS Sans Serif, 0
>   2898. Information VSI_MS_Sans_Serif16.0_1_0, MS Sans Serif, 0 
> DEBUG: Error 
> 2826: Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends beyond the
>   boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels There was an
>   unexpected error installing this package. Likely problem with this
>   package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm,
>   Line2, to the right
>  DEBUG: Error 2826: Control BannerBmp
>   FatalErrorForm on dialog extends beyond the boundaries of the dialog
>   to the right by 3 pixels There was an unexpected error installing this
>   package. Likely problem with this package. The error code is 2826. The
>   arguments are: FatalErrorForm, BannerBmp, to the right
>   2898. Information VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400, MS Sans Serif,
>   0 
> DEBUG: Error 2826: Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends
>   beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels There was
>   an unexpected error installing this package. Likely problem with this
>   package. The error code is 2826. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm,
>   Line1, to the right 
> 13:19:48 Operation: FatalErrorForm. Dialog created
>   Action ended
>  13:19:52: FatalErrorForm. Return Value 1. Action ended
>   
> 13:19:52: INSTALL. Return value 3.
>
> Property (C): VSDNETURLMSG = Setup requires .NET Framework version
>   [1]. Install .NET Framework and run setup again. You can obtain the
>   .NET Framework from the Web. Downloading now?
>  Property (C): VSDIISMSG
>   = The installer requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or later, and Windows XP or later, and can not run on Windows 2000. Install Internet
>   Information Server or a more recent operating system and run the
>   installer.
>  Property (C): = VSDUIANDADVERTISED This announcement will
>   not be installed because it might be unreliable. Contact your system
>   administrator to change the package installation in the basic option.
>   Property (C): VSDNETMSG = The installation program requires the .NET
>   Framework version [1]. Install .NET Framework and rerun the installer.
>   Property (C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is
>   unavailable. Internet Information Server might not be running or you
>   can that the path exists and is redirected to another computer. Check
>   the status of this virtual directory in Internet Services Manager.
>   Property (C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install. The latest version of
>   the product is already installed

.

Comment: it is simple service or WCF?

Comment: Look into Windows Event Log for msi exceptions - maybe there you will find some additional  exception information.

Comment: @user6002727 it is a simple service

Comment: @VitaliyK thank you: the event ID is 11708 anf the source MsiInstaller, the user "xxxx\Administrator" and the computer "xxxx"

Comment: @user1785210 this means. 11708 Product [2] – Installation operation failed Error message that the installation of the product failed.

Site:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Could you try to run this command: msiexec /i <yourapp>.msi /l* LogFile.txt and look into  generated log file for errors

Comment: @VitaliyK thank you, i've done it. I've missed to tell that Windows Xp runs on a virtual machine VMWare...

Comment: And what you see in installation logs? Any errors?

Comment: @VitaliyK I've edit the question, thank you

Comment: Seems IIS is not installed on your vitual machine. Check it in  system features&components.

Comment: @VitaliyK but why it asks to download ".NET" if it is already installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIRCA_CheckFX is the VS setup custom action that checks for the .NET Runtime, and it's failing, that's why it returns 3, and the rest of it is just whining about the dialogs not being perfect.

You didn't say which version of VS setup you're using, but the most likely explanation is that XP (which is unsupported) is missing some dependency (or OS API) that the custom action code needs. Or it's using a search for the runtime that is inappropriate for a runtime installed on XP.  If you built your setup with an ancient VS setup (VS 2003 or VS 2005) it might have more chance of working because XP was supported when they were around.

Comment: Thank you, i've built the project with Visual Studio 2010 instead then Visual Studio 2015 and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, the error looks like it is to do with the error dialog ironically.

I think that the dialog is about 3px too small on XP for some reason. If you make the error dialog slightly larger, or the controls slightly smaller, you may fix the issue, or more likely, get a better error message. I've extracted the relevant bits from the log.

> DEBUG: Error 2826: Control Line2 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends
>   beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
>
> DEBUG: Error 2826: Control BannerBmp FatalErrorForm on dialog extends
>   beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels
>
> DEBUG: Error 2826: Control Line1 on dialog FatalErrorForm extends
>   beyond the boundaries of the dialog to the right by 3 pixels

I avoid VS Installer like the plague, so if you can't modify the dialog in there, try using an MSI Editor like InstEdit (freely downloadable).